# how can you split cell data into different cells in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse this webpage into a pandas dataframe to analyze, but the page is set up such that the table only has two columns of use, one with the name and the other containing all the other information as a single cell.

For example, with my code below:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = "https://education.scripps.edu/alumni/graduate-alumni-list/index.html"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('tbody')
td = table.find_all('td')
data = []
for element in td:
    sub_data = []
    for sub_element in element:
        try:
            sub_data.append(sub_element.get_text())
        except:
            continue
    data.append(sub_data)

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df = dataFrame[[1,3]]
df = df.dropna()
```

So df.iat[0,1] would have the program, defense year, advisor, dissertation title, and undergraduate institution. The HTML only uses "br" and "strong" to separate these values, and I am wondering if there is any way to separate this text into different columns so the columns would be "name", "program", "defense year" and such, instead of one cell containing all the information.

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After try: and before sub_data.append line in your code you should split your sub_element text by "<br>". You can try the following:

```
sub_data_splitted = sub_element.get_text().split("<br>").
# After that you are able to use each field of the data i.e. 
program = sub_data_splitted[0].split(":")[1]
defense_year = sub_data_splitted[1].split(":")[1]
advisor = sub_data_splitted[2].split(":")[1]
dissertation_title = sub_data_splitted[3].split(":")[1]
ug_institution = sub_data_splitted[4].split(":")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- You can use `.stripped_strings()` to get a list of data from each `<tr>` of the table.
- Since you only need the values and not the titles (like Name, Defense Year, etc.) Use List comprehension to select only the required values.
- Append the list to a dataframe.

Here is how it is done.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://education.scripps.edu/alumni/graduate-alumni-list/index.html"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
t = soup.find('table').find('tbody')
trs = t.find_all('tr')
data = []
for i in trs:
    l = [x for i,x in enumerate(list(i.stripped_strings)) if i%2 == 0]
    data.append(l)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

```
                                0  ...     6
0              Abbott, PhD, Jason  ...  None
1      Adam, PhD, Gregory Charles  ...  None
2         Adhikari, PhD, Pramisha  ...  None
3    Al-Bassam, PhD, Jawdat M. H.  ...  None
4        Albertshofer, PhD, Klaus  ...  None
..                            ...  ...   ...
682           Zhou, PhD, Jiacheng  ...  None
683    Zhou, PhD, Zhaohui (Sunny)  ...  None
684                Zhu, PhD, Ruyi  ...  None
685                 Zhu, PhD, Yan  ...  None
686          Zuhl, PhD, Andrea M.  ...  None

[687 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd

url = "https://education.scripps.edu/alumni/graduate-alumni-list/index.html"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('tbody')
td = table.find_all('td')
data = {}
names = []
prev_name = None
for element in td:
    sub_data = {}
    for sub_element in element:
        try:
            data[sub_element['alt']] = {}
            prev_name = sub_element['alt']
        except:
            sub_element = str(sub_element).replace('</strong>', '').replace('<br/>', '</strong>')
            temp = BeautifulSoup(sub_element)
            if len(temp.find_all('strong')) > 0:
                temp = [str(i.string) for i in temp.find_all('strong') if i.string is not None]
                temp = {i.split(':', 1)[0] : i.split(':', 1)[1] for i in temp if ':' in i}
                data[prev_name] = temp


df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df = df.T.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={'index' : 'Name'}, inplace=True)
```